# How to filter a twitter user by counting the number of 1st and 2nd order followers?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First of all I apologize for the question. I just started with neo4j

I need to find a relevant twitter user whose number of followers, counting the followers of first and second level together, is 1111. I need to show the name and number of followers.

First of all, I just want to get the number 1111 and then find a way to show the name, so I wrote the following:

```
MATCH p = (a:TwitterUser)-[r:FOLLOWS*1..2]->(b:RelevantTwitterUser) 
WITH  COUNT(r) as nf2
WHERE nf2 = 1111
RETURN nf2
```

The result:

> (no changes, no records)

Database information:

[image]

Comment: sum of followers of level 1 and level 2 to be exact `1111`?
and what about if a user has `1111 followers` and his `followers` has some `follower`s, in that case what you expecting the result?

Comment: i think you want those users who has greater then 1111 followers, including level 2 followers, right?

Comment: No, only the user wich has exactly 1111 followers as the result of the sum of both (1st and 2nd level), I'm sure that there is 1 and only one user.

Comment: ok , check answer

Comment: From the above screenshot, It looks like you don't have data in the database.

Comment: I don't understand why do you say that. For example when I clik in *FOLLOWS* I can see a graph, and in Text: "p" = 
│[{"createdAt":"Tue Mar 09 11:3│
│7:56 +0000 2010","statusesCoun│
│t":"338","utcOffset":"3600","g│
│eoEnabled":"1","verified":"0",│
│"timeZone":"Madrid","location" *[...]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved when I have RETURN ***userName***.

**As curiosity if anyone knows how it could be done without having to RETURN the userName I would give a +1 in the comment**.

Possibilities:

> 1

```
MATCH (a:TwitterUser)-[f:FOLLOWS*1..2]->(b:RelevantTwitterUser) 
WITH  b.userName as user , COUNT(f) as nf2
WHERE nf2 = 1111
RETURN user, nf2
```

> 2

```
MATCH (a:TwitterUser)-[f:FOLLOWS*1..2]->(b:RelevantTwitterUser) 
WITH  b.userName as user , COUNT(*) as nf2
WHERE nf2 = 1111
RETURN user, nf2
```

> [...]

Comment: while your answer could be good for this question it's always better to add some explanation to it. Please take few minutes to improve your answer. tnx

Comment: Done. Thank you @DaFois for helping us to better understanding the community.

Comment: `*2` is not appropriate, since it would only match 2-hop paths -- ignoring first-hop followers who are not themselves followed by anyone.

Comment: True! Thanks for the observation, I have already corrected the missing one.

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATED]

In your query, since `r` is a *list* of relationships, `COUNT(r)` would just return the number of lists (not the size of each list or all lists -- and especially not the number of *distinct* items across all lists).

The following query should return a list of the 1111 distinct followers, if indeed there are exactly that many, for user `u`. (It is not necessary to return the count, since it will always be 1111.)

```
MATCH p = (u:TwitterUser)-[:FOLLOWS*..2]->(:RelevantTwitterUser)
UNWIND TAIL(NODES(p)) AS follower
WITH u, COLLECT(DISTINCT follower) AS followers
WHERE SIZE(followers) = 1111
RETURN u, followers;
```

The `UNWIND` clause gets the matched follower nodes, and the `WITH` clause uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` with the `DISTINCT` option to get a list of the distinct follower nodes for `u`.

Comment: It does not work for me, it can be the version (3.1.5). I do not know.

Result:
(no changes, no records)

Comment: I have updated my answer to use `u` as the grouping key for the `COLLECT` aggregating function. That will produce a list of distinct followers for each user, `u` (instead of for all users). If this still does not work, are you sure you have a user with exactly 1111 followers up to 2 hops away?